# How do I deserialize a JSON string with a property called "*"?

Tags: c#, .net, json, javascriptserializer

I have a **desktop** application which uses the `JavaScriptSerializer` class to decode a bit of JSON returned by the MediaWiki web application. This was mostly pretty easy to figure out, but there's a particular JSON response that includes "*" as one of the field names and I dunno what to do with it.

Here's some sample JSON:

```
{
    "warnings": {
        "login": {
            "result": "OK",
            "*": "blah blah blah"
        }
    }
}
```

I've created a `rLogin` class to contain the results for the `login` subobject, and in that class I've created a String `enter code here`object for `result` but I don't know what to do for the other field.  Obviously I can't create a field in my class with a name of `*` so how does one get the value?

Comment: Is the `result` key actually missing quotes in the real file or was that just a typo in the question example?

Comment: Oh that was just a typo.. sorry about that.  There isn't actually a result field at all... I just added that as an example of another field for which I'd added a string object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a [JavaScriptConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The JavaScriptConverter class enables you to implement serialization
>   and deserialization processes for managed types that are not natively
>   supported by the JavaScriptSerializer class.

It's not the most straightforward because of the nesting, but I've knocked a crude one up and tested it successfully in [Linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/). The relevant part here is our implementation of `Deserialize()`:

```
public class ResultConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<Type> supportedTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(Warnings) };

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes => supportedTypes;

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var warningsDictionary = dictionary["warnings"] as IDictionary<string, object>;
        var loginDictionary = warningsDictionary["login"] as IDictionary<string, object>;

        var login = new Login
        {
            Result = loginDictionary["result"] as string,
            Details = loginDictionary["*"] as string,
        };

        return new Warnings { Login = login };
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Supporting classes and usage:

```
void Main()
{
    string json = @"{ ""warnings"": { ""login"": { result: ""OK"", ""*"": ""blah blah blah"" } } }";

    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    js.RegisterConverters(new List<JavaScriptConverter> { new ResultConverter() });
    var result = js.Deserialize<Warnings>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public class Login
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}

public class Warnings
{
    public Login Login { get; set; }
}
```

In our output we now have "blah blah blah" in the `Details` property.